# Is there a scripting or command-line interface to the Apache mod_info module?

Tags: apache2, python, administration

I am running an Apache2 web-server. I would like to be able to access the kind of information made available by the mod_info and mod_status modules via the command-line, either through a scripting language such as Python or through a command-line utility. Is this a possibility?

For example, I can use `curl` to inspect header information:

```
curl --head 'http://127.0.0.1/server-info'
```

This gives me a convenient way to verify that my header configuration settings have taken effect and are working properly. It would be nice if there were a similar way (syntactically speaking) to verify other settings.

I've considered parsing the output of the 'mod_info', but I'm hoping that there is a preexisting (and cleaner) solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command line interface into the two modules you have mentioned. They are designed to be output to the browser by creating a location entry in the conf file and using the `SetHandler` directive. Unfortunately there is no predefined "cleaner" solution to parse through the data and you may need to roll your own.